# Return multiple rows from multi SELECT subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-variables

**query**

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT NAME FROM product_component) AS pcNAME,
    (SELECT PROJECT_NAME FROM jira_project) AS jpNAME, 
    (SELECT FILTER_NAME FROM jira_filter) AS jfNAME
```

Each SELECT will return an indeterminate number of rows. I get the error `Subquery returns more than 1 row`. My desired output will be something like this (quick sketch):

```
=======================================
|   pcNAME   |   jpNAME   |  jfNAME   |
=======================================
|    data    |    data    |    data   |
+------------+------------+-----------+
|    data    |    data    |    data   |
+------------+------------+-----------+
|    data    |    data    |    data   |
+------------+------------+-----------+
|            |    data    |    data   |
+------------+------------+-----------+
|            |    data    |    data   |
+------------+------------+-----------+
|            |    data    |           |
+------------+------------+-----------+
```

Each column may produce a different number of rows than the others. So I will want to produce the amount of rows from the max and then blank out the others that don't fill the max number of rows.

**NOTE:** None of these tables have a shared column so cannot achieve as `INNER JOIN`

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Do these table have auto increment id fields? If yes, you can use those to join them.

Comment: @GarethD the tuples do not matter. All I am attempting to do is display all data form those 3 tables. Data can be unordered

Comment: @Shadow yes, they all have a AI field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to handle this in MySQL to use to variables, `union all` and aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(NAME) as NAME, MAX(PROJECT_NAME) as PROJECT_NAME,
       MAX(FILTER_NAME) as FILTER_NAME
FROM ((SELECT (@rnpc := @rnpc + 1) as rn, NAME, NULL as PROJECT_NAME, NULL as FILTER_NAME
      FROM product_component CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rnpc := 0) params
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT (@rnpn := @rnpn + 1) as rn, NULL, PROJECT_NAME, NULL as FILTER_NAME
      FROM jira_project CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rnpn := 0) params
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT (@rnf := @rnf + 1) as rn, NAME, NULL as PROJECT_NAME, NULL as FILTER_NAME
      FROM jira_filter CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rnf := 0) params
      )
     ) t
GROUP BY rn
ORDER BY rn;
```

Comment: Brilliant answer!! Thank you. Never thought of the variables